# Unable to get the CSS :not() selector working as required

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit stumped with trying to get the CSS :not() selector to work for me in a very specific way.  I've spent a huge amount of time looking around and found some good resources like this [page](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/the-css3-not-selector/) but in the end I had to admit defeat.  I'm hoping a more enlightened soul here will be able to help.

Basically, I want to blur some text while leaving other bits of text untouched.  Please see below for the HTML/CSS:

```
<div class="top-hide">
    <p class="reveal">Paragraph 1</p>
    <div class="reveal">Paragraph 2</div>
    <div class="reveal"><p>Paragraph 3</p></div>
    <div><p class="reveal">Paragraph 4</p></div>
    <div class="reveal"><p class="reveal">Paragraph 5</p></div>
    <p>Paragraph 6</p>
    <div>Paragraph 7</div>
    <div><p>Paragraph 8</p></div>
</div>

.top-hide :not(.reveal) {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

I would like to reveal paragraphs 1 to 5, while 6 to 8 should be blurred out. However, paragraphs 1, 2 and 5 are revealed with the others blurred out.  Could you please tell me why my CSS doesn't work and construct the correct CSS to achieve my goal.

I've also constructed a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fz5eswwy/) to demonstrate the problem I'm facing.

Many thanks

Comment: :not() is only supported on modern browsers and not on IE. Do you want a solution with JavaScript/jQuery instead which handles cross browser issues?

Comment: @SaumilSoni — MSIE has supported `:not` for over four years.

Comment: @Quentin My apologies but the link provided by pn206 specifically says that it is not supported in IE

Comment: That's the trouble with using documentation from 2008.

Comment: @Quentin Damm I didn't looked at the dates, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: So you want to keep the current html but make the changes in CSS, correct?

Comment: @Adam Buchanan Smith - yes please, that's the solution I'm after, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. Here you go:

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="top-hide">
        <p class="reveal">Paragraph 1</p>
        <div class="reveal">Paragraph 2</div>
        <div class="reveal"><p>Paragraph 3</p></div>
        <!-- It doesn't work for the paragraph 3 is because, at first the 
        browser checks if `.top-hide :not(.reveal)` case is met when looking at 
        `div.top-hide > div.reveal`, It does not. Then again, it checks for 
        `.top-hide :not(.reveal)` when it looks at `div.top-hide p`, but this time
        the `.top-hide :not(.reveal)` is met. -->

        <div><p class="reveal">Paragraph 4</p></div>
        <!-- In this case, the case is met for `div.top-hide div` -->

        <div class="reveal"><p class="reveal">Paragraph 5</p></div>
        <p>Paragraph 6</p>
        <div>Paragraph 7</div>
        <div><p>Paragraph 8</p></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.top-hide :not(.reveal) {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}

.top-hide .reveal, .top-hide .reveal *{
    color: black;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Updated [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fz5eswwy/3/)

Answer (score 4):

```
<div><p class="reveal">Paragraph 4</p></div>
```

Despite the paragraph having `class="reveal"`, the selector you wrote matches the **div** element (and then the paragraph inherits the transparent foreground colour and the shadow).

There is no parent selector in CSS, so you can't exclude divs that contain elements with class="reveal".

The simplest solution to this would be to:

1. Move all the `class="reveal"`s to the child elements (i.e. `<div class="reveal"><p>Paragraph 4</p></div>` *and*
2. Use a child combinator so you only hide the unrevealed *children* (and not the descendants): `.top-hide > :not(.reveal)`

Comment: Thanks for that @Quentin, unfortunately, there are certain combinations where doing that would reveal too much...

Answer (score 1):

The nested elements are messing up with the selector... Example:

```
<div class="reveal"><p>Paragraph 3</p></div>
```

The `div` makes it reveal, but the `p` invalidates it. A quick fix is to always set the class in the first level (direct children), and then use a direct child selector:

[**Updated JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fz5eswwy/2/)

```
.top-hide > :not(.reveal) {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer regarding why it doesn't work makes sense and it's what I suspected was happening.  However, as I commented to @Quentin, I'm currently not able to use your solution.